# lldbclient.py on multiple connected android devices

Tags: debugging, android-ndk, adb, android-source, remote-debugging

lldbclient.py does not seem to work with multiple adb devices connected to the same host.
Let's suppose I have multiple android devices attached to my host.
adb devices
USB_device_01        device
USB_device_02        device
10.145.80.01:5555    device
10.145.80.02:5555    device
lldbclient.py does seem to work only when I have to disconnect all the other devices.
Is there a way to make the script pick up the right device ?
For the network devices they could be connected or disconnected through adb connect/disconnect.
But that does not seem to work on the USB devices.

I'm expecting the lldbclient.py to have an argument or a parameter to allow the device selection, but I didn't find any example like that in the documentation.

Comment: is the answer below helping to figure out the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Considering that `lldbclient.py` uses `ArgumentParser` class from `gdbrunner` then you can use the following parameters:

```
        "-d" to "directs commands to the only connected USB device"

        "-e" to "directs commands to the only connected emulator"

        "-s" to "directs commands to device/emulator with the given serial"
```

The source code is available [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/python-packages/gdbrunner/__init__.py)